# Good Introductions to Kants Critique of Judgment

Tags: kant, aesthetics, critique-of-pure-reason, teleology

Can somebody recommend any? I have come across Wicks & Hughes so far, but I am finding it very difficult. I am also finding it incredibly difficult reading through the Critique itself. Any advice on how to make things more pleasant?

I am mainly interested in the *2nd part* of the critique, so it would be great to have a introduction or commentary that would reflect that and not focus on the 1st part only.

Comment: For example: John Zammito, [The Genesis of Kant's Critique of Judgment](https://books.google.it/books?id=WHekZCIodTcC&printsec=frontcover) (1992).

Comment: There is a pretty good Blackwell Dictionary of Kant (Cargill) that I find very useful in reading Kant in English on my own....though you may be at a deeper level of detail than I am. To me, it is often helpful just to see the root words in German, the citations, and the lists of related terms.  I am not qualified to judge the interpretations or level of scholarship, but most entries are fairly substantive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A general advice regarding an approach to this book

Understanding the book without having looked into the rest of the system seems hopeless to me.

As a more broad possibility and an embedding into the whole history Kants own works and system as well as German Idealism as a whole I would suggest Eckart Förster's [*The Twenty-Five Years of Philosophy*](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674055162&content=reviews)

For the same reason, Paul Guyer's [The Cambridge Companion to Kant](http://www.cambridge.org/ke/academic/subjects/philosophy/history-philosophy/cambridge-companion-kant) would be another alternative.

### If you, as your comment states, already *are* an expert in Kant's terminology:

The *classical* one would be of H. Cassirer, son of Ernst Cassirer, already published in 1938: [A Commentary on Kant's Critique of Judgment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0389039594). Parts of the contemporary review by H.J. Paton (!) are available [here](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=3439840&fileId=S0031819100014285).

A more modern work would be the [Routledge Philosophy GuideBook to Kant on Judgment
From Robert Wicks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0415281113), new edition from 2007, which explicitly mentions the lack of literature on the book as a whole since Cassirer's commentary because of the focus on the aesthetics of Kant in the first part of the book, claiming to close the gap in the preface, [pages X and XI](https://books.google.de/books?id=0P2BAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR9&lpg=PR9&dq=judgement+Kant+commentary&source=bl&ots=RPIiEhq9vz&sig=H3GBKgfM39X-MJe8R9wYqetJab0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwintr3igMDLAhWKHpoKHW5NALg4ChDoAQgyMAk#v=onepage&q=judgement%20Kant%20commentary&f=false).

The proposal of @MauroAllegranza [John Zammito, The Genesis of Kant's Critique of Judgment (1992)](https://books.google.it/books?id=WHekZCIodTcC&printsec=frontcover) may be worth a look as well, but I don't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

The most selling and very powerful book on the Third Critique in American academia is Rudolf Makkreel, *Imagination and Interpretation in Kant: The Hermeneutical Import of the Critique of Judgment*---http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/I/bo3774594.html

Also, Phillip is correct and that piece of Cassirer's *Kant's Life and Work*, which is a very important source!

Comment: Interesting information, I'll surely have a look into it *hat tip*